# Why javascript uncaught reference error for beautify library

Tags: javascript

I'm testing https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-beautify

with

https://jsfiddle.net/pLwcv97x/

```
  window.addEventListener('load', (e) => {
    console.log("test");
    beautify("<html></html>", { indent_size: 2, space_in_empty_paren: true })
  });
```

I added library in html

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-beautify/1.14.6/beautify.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-beautify/1.14.6/beautify-css.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-beautify/1.14.6/beautify-html.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can use the Stack Snippets feature right on this site instead of an external fiddle.

Comment: Per the source code the function you should be using is ```js_beautify``` not ```beautify```

Comment: Or maybe `html_beautify`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `js_beautify` instead of `beautify`:

```js
js_beautify("<html></html>", { indent_size: 2, space_in_empty_paren: true })
```

Comment: then there is a mistypo in their example, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

There could be a number of reasons why you are getting an Uncaught Reference Error when using the Beautify library. It is possible that the library is not loaded correctly, or that there is a conflict with another library. It is also possible that the code you are using is not compatible with the Beautify library.